# gfortran include directory with subroutines

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I have programmed some fortran subroutines. I saved the subroutines in a Desktop folder called `subroutines`. When I compile a fortran program, say `main.f90` (located in a different folder than `subroutines`), that uses  subroutines (e.g. `sub1.f90`, `sub2.f90`) of the folder `subroutines`,  I need to **copy every subroutine into the folder of `main.f90`** and then compile like this:

`gfortran -o main main.f90 sub1.f90 sub2.f90`

which outputs the executable file as desired.

My question is: Is there any compiler option in gfortran to include files from the `subroutine` folder **without** having to copy each subroutine to the folder of `main.f90`?

I have tried these two options:

`gfortran -L/home/user/Desktop/subroutines -o main main.f90 sub1.f90 sub2.f90`

`gfortran -I/home/user/Desktop/subroutines -o main main.f90 sub1.f90 sub2.f90`

both of these compiler options return the error: `gfortran: No such file or directory`

The only available fortran compiler in my PC is gfortran (no ifort).

Comment: You are almost certainly better off compiling each `.f90` file separately and then linking finally.  The `-I` flag relates to the search path for include files and module files.

Comment: Youbare probably looking for some build system, such as make or some better modern alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the full path to the subroutine file. So you would augment your compilation as

```
gfortran -o main main.f90 subroutines/sub1.f90 subroutines/sub2.f90
```

or a clever way to do this call is to use expansions as so

```
gfortran -o main main.f90 subroutines/{sub1,sub2}.f90
```

where the curly brackets will expand to be the same as the first complication I show.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the second method you mentioned. This was very useful.